# ogr2ogr ST_Difference operation on OGRVRTDataSource

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to subtract from one shapefile the portions of another which overlap using the following:

```
land.shp: subunits.shp lakes.shp
  COOKIE=subunits CUTTER=lakes; \
  echo '<OGRVRTDataSource><OGRVRTLayer name="'$$COOKIE'"><SrcDataSource>'$$COOKIE'.shp</SrcDataSource></OGRVRTLayer><OGRVRTLayer name="'$$CUTTER'"><SrcDataSource>'$$CUTTER'.shp</SrcDataSource></OGRVRTLayer></OGRVRTDataSource>' | \
  ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" \
    land.shp /vsistdin/ \
    -dialect sqlite \
    -sql "SELECT ST_Difference($$COOKIE.geometry,$$CUTTER.geometry) AS geometry FROM $$COOKIE,$$CUTTER"

lakes.shp: ne_10m_lakes.shp
  ogr2ogr \
    -t_srs EPSG:4326 \
    -clipdst -92.956317 49.113085 -74.952721 40.992926 \
    lakes.shp \
    ne_10m_lakes.shp \

subunits.shp: ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp
  ogr2ogr \
    -where "ADM0_A3 IN('CAN')" \
    -t_srs EPSG:4326 \
    subunits.shp \
    ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp
```

(Makefile, sorry about the long lines)

The result I'm getting is identical to the input, which is what should result if the 2nd file (CUTTER) is empty. It's not, however, and as a sanity check, when I reverse the order of the first line (COOKIE=lakes CUTTER=subunits) and leave everything else the same the result is what I'd expect: the US part of the lakes minus everything else. That suggests to me that the query itself is fine. Is there something else I might be missing?

Here are the contents of the .prj files. subunits.prj:

`GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]`

lakes.prj:

`GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]`

The only difference being that lakes.prj uses floats for all numbers, though they're otherwise the same.

TL;DR: I want the area of the polygon around the Great Lakes to follow the shoreline, not the int'l. border.